# TSP tutorial example of google's or-tools crashes

Tags: python-3.5, or-tools

The example program for TSP problems crashes on my machine (ubuntu 16.04) with the following message:

```
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
F0430 14:40:29.424594 15961 search.cc:2658] Check failed: step > 0 (0 vs. 0) 
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

- installed binary via `pip3 install ortools`
- changed print statements for python 3
- replaced `pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()` with `pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultModelParameters()`

The entire program, taken from https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/tsp/tsp#program1,  is below:

```
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2

# Distance callback
class CreateDistanceCallback(object):
  """Create callback to calculate distances between points."""
  def __init__(self):
    """Array of distances between points."""

    self.matrix = [
    [   0, 2451,  713, 1018, 1631, 1374, 2408,  213, 2571,  875, 1420, 2145, 1972], # New York
    [2451,    0, 1745, 1524,  831, 1240,  959, 2596,  403, 1589, 1374,  357,  579], # Los Angeles
    [ 713, 1745,    0,  355,  920,  803, 1737,  851, 1858,  262,  940, 1453, 1260], # Chicago
    [1018, 1524,  355,    0,  700,  862, 1395, 1123, 1584,  466, 1056, 1280,  987], # Minneapolis
    [1631,  831,  920,  700,    0,  663, 1021, 1769,  949,  796,  879,  586,  371], # Denver
    [1374, 1240,  803,  862,  663,    0, 1681, 1551, 1765,  547,  225,  887,  999], # Dallas
    [2408,  959, 1737, 1395, 1021, 1681,    0, 2493,  678, 1724, 1891, 1114,  701], # Seattle
    [ 213, 2596,  851, 1123, 1769, 1551, 2493,    0, 2699, 1038, 1605, 2300, 2099], # Boston
    [2571,  403, 1858, 1584,  949, 1765,  678, 2699,    0, 1744, 1645,  653,  600], # San Francisco
    [ 875, 1589,  262,  466,  796,  547, 1724, 1038, 1744,    0,  679, 1272, 1162], # St. Louis
    [1420, 1374,  940, 1056,  879,  225, 1891, 1605, 1645,  679,    0, 1017, 1200], # Houston
    [2145,  357, 1453, 1280,  586,  887, 1114, 2300,  653, 1272, 1017,    0,  504], # Phoenix
    [1972,  579, 1260,  987,  371,  999,  701, 2099,  600, 1162,  1200,  504,   0]] # Salt Lake City

  def Distance(self, from_node, to_node):
    return int(self.matrix[from_node][to_node])
def main():

  # Cities
  city_names = ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Minneapolis", "Denver", "Dallas", "Seattle",
                "Boston", "San Francisco", "St. Louis", "Houston", "Phoenix", "Salt Lake City"]
  tsp_size = len(city_names)
  num_routes = 1    # The number of routes, which is 1 in the TSP.
  # Nodes are indexed from 0 to tsp_size - 1. The depot is the starting node of the route.
  depot = 0

  # Create routing model
  if tsp_size > 0:
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(tsp_size, num_routes, depot)
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.RoutingModel.DefaultModelParameters()

    # Create the distance callback, which takes two arguments (the from and to node indices)
    # and returns the distance between these nodes.
    dist_between_nodes = CreateDistanceCallback()
    dist_callback = dist_between_nodes.Distance
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(dist_callback)
    # Solve, returns a solution if any.
    assignment = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
    if assignment:
      # Solution cost.
      print("Total distance: {} miles".format(assignment.ObjectiveValue()))
      # Inspect solution.
      # Only one route here; otherwise iterate from 0 to routing.vehicles() - 1
      route_number = 0
      index = routing.Start(route_number) # Index of the variable for the starting node.
      route = ''
      while not routing.IsEnd(index):
        # Convert variable indices to node indices in the displayed route.
        route += str(city_names[routing.IndexToNode(index)]) + ' -> '
        index = assignment.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
      route += str(city_names[routing.IndexToNode(index)])
      print("Route:\n\n{}".format(route))
    else:
      print('No solution found.')
  else:
    print('Specify an instance greater than 0.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Here is a working example (on the upcoming 7.0 release) https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/ortools/constraint_solver/samples/tsp_distance_matrix.py